# How to enable "Other" or "Manual" user login in ubuntu 14.04.1?

Tags: login, users, login-screen

I found the other one with the lightdm thing but it doesnt work because its for 12.04!
does anyone know how to enable the manual login like in XUbuntu where you can type in the user and the password?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To hide your users at login screen ,open terminal and type following command

`gksudo gedit /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf`

Now add this line in it.

```
 greeter-show-manual-login=true
```

It will hide the username at login screen. You need to enter your username to login.